# Why is my Dataflow pipeline not showing steps?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

[image]

When I run the examples I get a pretty picture showing the flow and I can monitor as it executes.  With my application it doesn't show the diagram and if I click on "Step" it displays nothing.

Adding screenshot of Job log.  No warnings or errors. BTW, I assumed the icon on the log entry with an "i" stands for Info level, but when I change the level from BASIC to ALL many more entries are added and they all have the same icon.  That is confusing. Icons should be more clear and should have hover tips, IMO.

[image]

Comment: Hi I'm on the Dataflow team. Sorry you are having trouble. Does your pipeline produce output and have you verified that the output is being produced? Can you please share the job id for one of the jobs for which no graph is showing?

Comment: @JeremyLewi yes, it produces my expected output.  Isn't that the Job ID in the first screenshot? Copied here for your convenience.  Job Name 
uotcpipeline-nwh02-1214220911
Job ID 
2015-12-14_14_09_19-5727579938330135228

Comment: I just saw this in the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#additional-support) 

**_Why doesn't the Dataflow Monitoring Interface report the status of my pipeline's output steps?_**

_This is a known issue with the Dataflow Monitoring Interface and will be addressed in a future release. As a workaround, you can view live output in the relevant Cloud Platform Console interface for your Cloud Platform output location, such as the Cloud Storage container explorer or the BigQuery console._  
I'm not sure if that applies to my situation or not.  It is kind of vague.

Comment: Thank you. We're investigating. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the Dataflow team. I'm sorry that you are encountering this issue.

I believe this is occurring because of the custom step names you're code is using.
From your screenshot of the job logs, it appears that some of these steps have been given names that represent a GCS storage path location.
I noticed this from this message in the logs:

Executing operation "gs://datalake/landing/...."

This fails to render in the monitoring UI and likely hits an assertion because slashes are disallowed characters.

In order to work around this issue would you please try removing the custom step names used in your code. Which seems to be set to gs:// style paths. You could also try specifying names for each step, without using special characters.
Please try running the job again after that change and see if the graph renders properly in the dataflow UI.

I have created a [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/89) to track this bug and prevent these slash characters from sent in the future in the dataflow SDK code.

Please let me know if you encounter any more issues.

Comment: Yes. That was it.  I was naming the transform the filename like TextIO.Read.named(inputFile).from(inputFile)  because without explicitly naming it was giving me this warning: _WARNING: Transform TextIO.Read2 does not have a stable unique name. This will prevent updating of pipelines._  The warning went away and the monitoring interface worked as expected when I hardcoded a name without slashes.  Thanks!